# Как сверстать таблицу

Tags: html, css, html5, table

[image: Таблица]

Всем привет, не могу сверстать такую же таблицу, а именно несколько колонок под "пакетами"

Comment: попробуйте воспользоваться онлайн генераторами таблиц, например https://apsolyamov.ru/files/html-table-generator.html

Comment: colspan не знаете как писать?

Comment: не получается обьеденить их

Answer (score 2):

> *Вижу цель, не вижу препятствий.*

Читаем про [colspan](https://basicweb.ru/html/tag_td_att_colspan.php) и [rowspan](https://basicweb.ru/html/tag_td_att_rowspan.php). Пользуемся [генератором таблиц](https://apsolyamov.ru/files/html-table-generator.html).

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }

td, th {
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="7">Пакетные услуги по образованию</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4">#</td>
    <th rowspan="4">Обучение (образование)</td>
    <th rowspan="4">Стоимость на 1-го человека</th>
    <th colspan="4">ПАКЕТЫ</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>базовый</th>
    <th>бронзовый</th>
    <th>серебряный</th>
    <th>золотой</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>20 - 30 человек на одном курсе</td>
    <td>от 31 человека на одном курсе</td>
    <td>от 76 человек на одном курсе</td>
    <td>свыше 120 человека на одном курсе</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">скидки по пакетам для рынка (продажи оплачиваются отдельно)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: спасибо, за ссылку на генератор HTML таблиц